# Run time for a recursive statement

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

Take the following pseudocode:

```
def dividethree (n) :
if ( n == 1) : 
   return True  #O(1)
if (( n % 3) == 0) :
   return ( dividethree ( n / 3) )
else :
   return False #O(1)
```

Would the big O runtime for this be **O(log<sub>3</sub>(n))** given that if we start with n we would divide by 3 going further and further down the binary tree? The if statement of n mod 3 is throwing me off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis seems correct although I wouldn't refer to this particular call chain as a binary tree since only one child can be spawned recursively. Disregard `n % 3` from a complexity standpoint because if you call it with an exponent of 3 such as 9, 27, 81... you have the worst case scenario.